# How to decode a urlstring in the right way in cocoa-touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

My encoded string from the server looks like this: "it-strategy%20RZ%20U%20texas".
How is it possible to decode this string back to "it-strategy RZ U texas"?

I have tried the method stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: , but I have still the percentages.

Answer (score 3):

Check that you use right encoding type:

```
NSString *s = @"it-strategy%20RZ%20U%20texas";
NSLog(@"Decoded string: %@", [s stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Comment: You mean `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Otherwise, non-ASCII characters will be encoded incorrectly (`NSASCIIStringEncoding` was treated as a synonym for `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`, last I checked) or not at all (anything not in ISO-Latin-1).

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried the method stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: , but I have still the percentages.

Are you looking at the string that message returned, or the string you sent that message to? If you're doing this:

```
NSString *myString = @"it-strategy%20RZ%20U%20texas";
[myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

That's wrong.

A method named like `stringByDoingSomething` or `arrayByAddingOrRemovingThings:` will *return a new object* with the requested modification applied—the original object, `myString` in the above example, remains unchanged.

The percent escape sequences have been replaced in the string that `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` returned. That's the string you need to look at:

```
NSString *unescapedString = [myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```